# What does “drone drop” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

There is the following passage in Maureen Dowd’s article titled, “Good riddance, Carrie Mathison” in April 4 New York Times:

> “The co-creator of “Homeland” on Showtime revealed recently that when
>   the new season starts, Claire Danes’s Carrie Mathison will no longer
>   work at the C.I.A.. The C.I.A. sisterhood is fed up with the flock of
>   fictional C.I.A. women in movies and on TV who guzzle alcohol as they
>   **bed hop and drone drop**, acting crazed and emotional, sleeping with
>   terrorists and seducing assets.”

I can guess what “bed hop” means, but I don’t understand what “drone drop” means, because "bed hop" doesn't link "drone drop" at all to me.
Is it a slanguage? How can I rephrase it in plain English words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, "drone drop" was chosen primarily because it makes a good rhyme with "bed hop", while also being symbolic of any number of improbable "high-tech spying" activities that a CIA agent could engage in.

Taken literally, "drone dropping" could be any of:

- shooting down an enemy drone
- dropping off a drone to be deployed and used for spying
- deploying a drone (dropping it out the back of a plane in order to launch it)
- killing a targeted individual ("dropping" them) via drone-mounted weapons
- dropping a bomb from a drone
- eavesdropping via drone-mounted parabolic microphones

It really doesn't matter which meaning you choose, the drone itself is the high-tech toy, and the CIA woman is working with it in some fashion.

If you wanted to rephrase the entire thing, I'd suggest something like

> ... as they engage in casual sex and perform unrealistic feats of cutting-edge-technology spying...

Answer (score 1):

It's about dropping such drones [as this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_combat_aerial_vehicle) .

Bombing with drones.

Comment: eavesdrop seems to make more sense in this context

Comment: @smci. I concur with your comment. The use of "drone drop" is too abrupt. Can CIA women drop drone bomb really? It's doesn't make sense.